# Getting unhandled request error in Nuxt 3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am learning now Nuxt3, and I can't figure why I am getting this error in console when I make request to my API backend:

```
[nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [400]  (400 Bad Request (http://localhost:3001/auth/login))
```

Exactly, I can't understand why my error is "unhandled", because my request code is like:

```
  const login = await $fetch('/api/auth/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: {
      email: formData.email,
      password: formData.password
    }
  }).catch(error => error.data)
```

and I using "catch" to handle error. Or I don't understand something about errors handling?

Comment: Can you use insomnia or postman to debug it outside of nuxt? Does it work there?